# Complex lambda expression as the key argument to sorted function

Tags: python, sorting

I have an example code:

```
In [60]: sorted([3, 1, None], key=lambda x: (x is None, x))
Out[60]: [1, 3, None]

In [61]: sorted([3, 1, None], key=lambda x: (x is not None, x))
Out[61]: [None, 1, 3]
```

I think I do understand what it does - looks like it allows skipping the `None` values of the key during sorting, otherwise sorting will raise a `TypeError` trying to compare `int` to `None` - but I don't understand how and why it works as it does. Specifically I am confused by the lambda function that returns a tuple.

I could not find anything relevant in the sorting [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto).
I would appreciate an explanation or a link to where this behavior is documented.

Comment: Do you understand how tuple comparison works? Given your data, do you understand how ``(True, 1) < (False, None)`` would be compared?

Comment: The lambda is creating a tuple, and tuples are compared element-wise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuples are compared and sorted in lexicographical order:

```py
>>> sorted([(0, 17), (1,15), (0,12), (0, 9), (1, 8), (1, 7), (0, 2)])
[(0, 2), (0, 9), (0, 12), (0, 17), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 15)]
>>> (0, 12) < (1, 9)
True
>>> (0, 12) < (0, 13)
True
>>> (1, 12) < (0, 9)
False
```

"Lexicographical order" is just a fancy word for "like words in an English dictionary": compare the first letter first, and only if the first letter is equal, then compare the second letter, and only if the first two letters are equal, then compare the third letter, etc.

Using a tuple as the key, the tuples will also be compared in lexicographical order.

In your case, `x is None` and `x is not None` evaluate to boolean values, `True` or `False`.

Boolean values can be compared too:

```py
>>> False < True
True
>>> True < False
False
```

As a result, `sorted([3, 1, None], key=lambda x: (x is None, x))` will consider that the smallest elements are those for which `x is None` is False, and the biggest elements are those for which `x is None` is True:

```py
>>> sorted([3, 1, None], key=lambda x: (x is None, x))
[1, 3, None]
>>> sorted(map(lambda x: (x is None, x), [3, 1, None]))
[(False, 1), (False, 3), (True, None)]
```

Comment: I get it now. I was missing the point that the result of the lambda expressions were compared with each other, not the iterable's items themselves. Combining this understanding with how tuple comparison works, it all makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @AndriiYurchuk Yes, and this behaviour is common to pretty much all python functions that have a `key` optional argument, not just `sorted` and `list.sort`. For instance, `max([3, -12, 5], key = abs)` will return `-12` because it has the highest absolute value, and `[list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby([1, 0, 2, 4, 8, 9, 7], key=lambda x: x % 2)]` will group adjacent elements by parity: `[[1], [0, 2, 4, 8], [9, 7]]`

Answer (score 1):

The `key` parameter of `sorted` is used to rank the values, in order of the elements if more than one.

What your code does is to put None first (or last), and as a secondary key, sort the non-None elements

First key: `[3, 1, None]` is mapped to `[False, False, True]` that is equivalent to `[0, 0, 1]` and pushes `None` to the end.

Second key is to break the tie between `3` and `1`

Comment: to mention why `None` is put as last when it is the only one that would return `True` is because the integer value of `True` is 1 and of `False` is 0 so (for the first case) it will sort first `[False (3), False (1), True (None)]` (True integer value is bigger and default is ascending order),  and then from there it will go `[1, 3, None]` because when using primary key `None` is higher so it stays there and the rest of the values get sorted because they have the same value in primary key

Comment: @Matiiss thanks, I could only provide a quick answer, but I see there is a complete one now ;)